# Filter Products using Storefront API in shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, storefront

We are developing filters functionality using Storefront API. We can write query with operators as given below to search within parent key such as "product_type" but we couldn't find way to search within child key.

```
.products(first: 10, query: "tag:blue AND product_type:sneaker") { $0
  ...
}
```

So can anyone help us to search within child key's such as variant selected options?

We are expecting query format like:

```
.products(first: 10, query: "selectedProductVarient.option1:M") { $0
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a query parameter to a nested connection, but the [productVariants() query argument](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2023-01/queries/productVariants#argument-productvariants-query) takes all of those filter parameters:

```
{
    productVariants(first: 10, query: "tag:foo product_type:bar option_1:baz") {
        nodes {
            id
            title
            product {
                productType
                tags
            }
        }
        pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
            endCursor
        }
    }
}
```

The `option_1` parameter is the name of the option ('size', 'color', etc.), not the value assigned to the variant. You might be better off querying the `title`.